# Number of visible table <tr> rows in a particular viewpart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am facing a problem while determining whether a row is completely visible in a view part or not.

I have created a dummy table as described below:-

```
<table id="alarmTable">
    <tr>
    <td>
        Hello
    <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Hello
    <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Hello
    <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Hello
    <td>
    </tr>
    <!-- with more data in the table -->
</table>
```

I want to determine whether a table row is visible within a view part or not. Suppose my table has 50 rows which are currently visible in browser window or on a small part of it.

Case 1 :- If i increase the number of rows beyond 50, a scroll-bar will automatically but the number of visible should still be 50. I want some piece of code that can take care of the actual visible rows and can return whether row in a table is visible or not.

case 2:- If i re-size browsers window and my view part gets resized. This time the number of visible rows can even be less than 50. How can i take care of this case and check whether a row is still visble or not.

Approach till now:-  I have tried many things including following code snippet :-

```
var visibleRows = $('#alarmTable tr:visible').length;
console.log("visible rows =" + visibleRows);
console.log("scroll height ="+ document.getElementById("alarmTable").scrollHeight);
console.log("client height ="+ document.getElementById("alarmTable").clientHeight);
console.log("offset height ="+ document.getElementById("alarmTable").offsetHeight);
```

but non of them is giving me the right parameters.

Note :- the table created above is just a dummy table for better understanding my problem.
[image: Image with all the rows visible in this case we need the row ids of the rows that are visible example in the image it is 8]

[image: In this case the rows ids of the rows that are actually visible should be returned. Half visible rows can be excluded]

[image: In this case if the window is resized the number of visible rows can be much smaller. In this case we need only the ids of the rows that are actually visible example :- in the image the number of visible rows is - 7]

Code returning the row id for the visible rows or the code returning whether a row is visible or not will be accepted as right answer.

Comment: 1) In case of first image clearly visible row should return 8 visible reasons. 2) In case of second image the visible rows should be ~41 3) in case of third image 7 clearly visible rows should be (half visible rows should not be included).Required method - method returning the row ids of the visible rows or returning true or false if a row is not visible is required.

Comment: It's a bit confusing, `:visible` returns all elements that consume space, i.e. that are not display `none` etc. regardless of wether or not you can actually see them on the screen. I'm guessing you want to count only the elements that are fully visible on the screen, or more correctly in the browser *viewport* ?

Comment: Also note that the posted HTML is invalid, you're not closing the cells.

Comment: Yes we require a code snippet that returns whether a row is visible in the viewport or not. Even a code snippet returning row ids of all the visible rows will be accepted.

Comment: [Try this plugin](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible): "This is a jQuery plugin which allows us to quickly check if an element is within the browsers visual viewport"

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to filter the elements based on wether or not they are visible in the viewport

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {

    var top    = $(this).scrollTop(),
        height = $(this).height();


    var visible = $('#alarmTable tr').filter(function() {
        var elTop    = $(this).offset().top,
            elHeight = $(this).height();

        return (elTop > top) && ((elTop + elHeight) < (top + height));
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uhss1zra/2/)